# questions about 2d map structure?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hello everyone,

i did the  turtlebot  gmapping  tutorial,got a map(width=768,height=512,resolution=0.05). does it mean that the actual size of the environment is (768 multiply by 0.05,512 multiply by0.05) ,the grid map of X  from [0,767],Y from [ 0,511]  or maybe  X-Y axes reverse,the [0,0]cell is the  lower left corner of the grid map,am i right?

then i saw the  [OccupancyGrid](http://docs.ros.org/api/nav_msgs/html/msg/OccupancyGrid.html) and[MapMetaData](http://docs.ros.org/api/nav_msgs/html/msg/MapMetaData.html) , and when i saw the [link1](http://answers.ros.org/question/73525/map-question-about-its-basic-2d-map-structure/),[link2](http://answers.ros.org/question/121406/what-mapinfooriginorientation-is-for/)and [link3](http://answers.ros.org/question/10268/where-am-i-in-the-map/),There are few points unclear.

1. when gmapping over with  the turtlebot stop ,but the node slam_gmapping not kill, then  i want to see the map data,so`rosrun echo /map > map_data.txt`,but the data are only three type: 0,100 and -1.But the [Image_format](http://wiki.ros.org/map_server#Image_format) said the "occupancy is represented as an integer in the range [0,100]",why?
2. from the experiment ,i got the map.info.origin.position=[-12.2,-12.2,0] , map.info.origin.orientation=[0,0,0,1],it suggest that there is no orientation between  the grid map frame coordinate and the /map frame coordinate,am i right ?how does the map_server  make  the grid map 's  X-Y axes  parallel to the /map frame's  X-Y?   if i do experiment in a rectangular totally free room ,i let the initial pose of  turtlebot  located in the diagonal of the environment ，facing to another  diagonal  corner,the  /map frame's   axes-X  isn't parallel   to the future build grid map  frame's axes-X, the /map frame's   axes-Y is also not parallel to map  frame's axes-Y,can i understand like this ?

Thanks  for your time and attention.sorry,my english is poor ,i hope i will not confuse you .your any ideas will be appreciated,thank you very much !!

jxl

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/194371/questions-about--2d-map--structure-?/) by [jxl](https://answers.ros.org/users/5454/jxl/) on ROS Answers with karma: 252 on 2014-10-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

First, your interpretations are correct.

1. It's still correct as per the definition. My guess is that it's easier for later algorithm to work with binary data than make the thresholding themselves as like this everyone is working on the same representation.
2. Yes this is correct. gmapping always uses 0 orientation. In principle you can use maps with other orientation, but I would not recommend that as as far as I known neither amcl nor the static map currently support that.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2014-10-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [paulbovbel](https://answers.ros.org/users/3632/paulbovbel/) on 2014-10-07**:
Addendum on 1: Map data is represented by an unsigned char, with 255 (or -1 after conversion to signed) being a special value to represent unknown space. [link](https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation/blob/hydro-devel/costmap_2d%2Finclude%2Fcostmap_2d%2Fcost_values.h)

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2014-10-07**:
Yes, this is also in the message spec: http://docs.ros.org/api/nav_msgs/html/msg/OccupancyGrid.html

**Comment by [jxl](https://answers.ros.org/users/5454/jxl/) on 2014-10-07**:
hello @dornhege,you  mean the value of the grid map published by /slam_gmapping node is only have three values,there is no   value  is (0,100),such as  87,18 and so on ?

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2014-10-07**:
It probably is internally, but is thresholed before publishing.

**Comment by [jxl](https://answers.ros.org/users/5454/jxl/) on 2014-10-07**:
sorry for late reply ,thank you .in other place i see  the origin.position  of the /map in  the /world can be set by yaml file which initialize map_server,where is it ? i only `rosrun  map_server map_saver -f  /tmp/map.yaml`,not set the origin ,does the origin get the fault value ?how can i set it?